can't reassign a class variable when inheriting in TypeScript
I am created a lexer parser etc etc. I created a custom call called Error, and a LexerErr class inehriting from the Error class.
The Error class accepts many variables in its constructor, one of the being a type which in this case I'm trying to set as "LexerError" but when I create a new instance, the type becomes undefined, I'm new to typescript and really confused since I tried all the things i found on the internet.
enter image description here
Code
Attempt #1
class Error { 
    type?: string;
    
    constructor(){
        if (type == undefined) {
            this.type = 'Uncaught';
        };
        console.log(this.type);
    };

};

class LexerErr extends Error {
    type = 'LexerError';
};

new LexerErr()`

Attempt #2
class Error { 
    type?: string;
    
    constructor(type?: string){
        if (type == undefined) {
            this.type = 'Uncaught';
        };
        console.log(this.type);
    };
};

class LexerErr extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super('LexerError');
    };
};

new LexerErr();

I tried just assigning the value to the class in Attempt #1 but that failed, then i tried assigning it in the constructor using the super method as seen in the second attempt

In the first snippet, you have if (type == undefined) { what is type? Did you mean this.type? Did you mean an constructor argument that was omitted?

Attempt #1 has a syntax error in that type is not defined. So I can't really answer anything about that.

Attempt #2 compiles and runs so I can tell you why that doesn't work.
    constructor(type?: string) {
      if (type == undefined) {
        this.type = "Uncaught";
      }
      console.log(this.type);
    }

Here, you never assign this.type except when type is undefined. So when you call super("LexerError"), here's what happens:

The Error constructor is invoked with the type parameter set to "LexerError". type is a now a local variable to this function that has nothing to do with this.type.
if (type == undefined) is false, so the branch is not executed.
console.log(this.type) returns undefined because this.type was never set to anything.

If you change this to:
    constructor(type?: string) {
      this.type = type ?? 'Uncaught'
      console.log(this.type);
    }

Then you get "LexerError" as expected. Here this.type is always being written to, so it will always have something.
See playground

Alternatively, you can use the class field initializer shorthand to accept and assign the constructor parameters to the class fields.
  class Error {
    constructor(public type: string = 'Uncaught') {
      console.log(this.type);
    }
  }

Note the public which declares this as a field on the instance, that will be populated for you.
Also note that there is a default value for the type parameter. This will be used if it is omitted.
See playground

This makes so much more sense, thank you so much! I’ll probably close the question later. Thank you!
